# ¿Cómo hacer .isin() con dos o mas columnas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos dataframes y la idea es hacer una comprobación con dos o más columnas.
con una columna lo tengo asi:

```
notIsin = df1.loc[~df1['codigo'].isin(df2['codigo'])]
```

mi idea seria hacer algo asi, que no esta permitido.

```
notIsin = df1.loc[~df1[['codigo','color']].isin(df2['codigo','color'])]
```

El objetivo es tener un nuevo DataFrame :"notIsin", en el que guarde solo los datos de df1 QUE NO ESTEN EN df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de usar el `isin()`con dos columnas sería algo así:

```
df1[(~df1.codigo.isin(df2.codigo))&(~df1.color.isin(df2.color))]
```

Sin embargo esto no te sirve, por que los dos valores se comparan de manera independiente y lo que necesitarías es la comparación de los valores a nivel de fila. Hay varias alternativas, las revisar en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe):

#### 1. Hacer un merge y filtrar los casos que son distintos

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'codigo' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'color' : [10, 11, 11, 13, 14], 'data': 0}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'codigo' : [1, 3, 2, 4, 6], 'color' : [10, 12, 11, 20, 10], 'data': 0})

df_all = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), 
                   on=['codigo','color'], 
                   how='left', indicator=True)

print(df_all)

   codigo  color  data_x  data_y     _merge
0       1     10       0     0.0       both
1       2     11       0     0.0       both
2       3     11       0     NaN  left_only
3       4     13       0     NaN  left_only
4       5     14       0     NaN  left_only
```

Como podrás observar, la columna `_merge` nos dice que filas son las coincidentes `both`, para saber las de `df1` que no están en `df2`:

```
df_all[df_all['_merge'] == 'left_only']
```

#### 2. Crear un índice por las dos columnas y usar `isin()` sobe los índices

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['codigo', 'color'])
df2 = df2.set_index(['codigo', 'color'])

df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

Es la forma más compacta, pero claro implica modificar los `dataframes` originales. Si las coincidencias las buscaras en todas las columnas, una forma rápida sería:

```
df1.loc[~df1.set_index(list(df1.columns)).index.isin(df2.set_index(list(df2.columns)).index)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, excelente respuesta. ¿Sí en la 2da opción uso df1 sin el .loc, implica alguna inconsistencia de los datos?.

Comment: @LucasDamian, en el contexto de mi respuesta, `loc` y  `[]` funcionan exactamente igual, son indistintos. Saludos